# Код не проходит все проверки. С чем это может быть связано?

Tags: python

На 1 скриншоте задание, на втором скриншоте 2 проверки, которые пройдены, но есть еще проверк(а/и), которые код не проходит. Если подскажете какие проверки может не проходить код - буду очень благодарен.

```py
a = set()
acc = input()
while acc != 'END':
    a.add(acc)
    acc = input()
spam = input()
while spam != 'END':
    if spam in a:
        a.delete(spam)
        spam = input()
print(len(a))
```

[image: Задание]

[image: Проверка]

Comment: Вторая строка `spam = input()` находится под условием `if` и поэтому выполняется, только если предыдущий спамер есть в множестве `a`. Если же его там нет — условие `if spam in a` не выполняется, из-за этого вторая строка `spam = input()` тоже не выполняется и ваш код зависнет в вечном цикле

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, помогло

Comment: `print(len(set(iter(input, "END"))-set(iter(input, "END"))))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
a = []
b = input()
while b != 'END':
    a.append(b)
    b = input()
a.append('END')
d = []
c = input()
while c != 'END':
    d.append(c)
    c = input()
d.append('END')
a.extend(d)
g = sorted(a)
last = g[-1]
for i in range(len(g)-2, -1, -1):
    if last == g[i]:
        del g[i]
    else:
        last = g[i]
if g:
    g.remove('END')
    d.remove('END')
    g = set(g) - set(d)
    print(len(g))
```

Слегка поспешил с написанием и я не силен в питоне. Выглядит тупо, но должно работать.

Comment: Ужас какой. . .

Comment: @andreymal Знаю XD. слишком много лишних переменных, и на 50% мог б сократить. Ну коммон, если код работает, значит все нормально